# I'm having trouble compiling a template from Overleaf on my personal LaTeX installation in my PC

Tags: templates, latex, bibtex, overleaf

I have to make a work using this template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/master-degree-thesis-unir-university-english/rtkkxskmdsbc

Now, I can use it directly on overleaf and it works relatively well, but because the final project is going to be quite heavy, I won't be able to use Overleaf until the end, so I have to use my home computer with LaTeX on it to compile it. However, I'm having trouble: When I download the whole template, it seems be able to be compiled using either XeLatex or LuaLatex. However, since it uses a *.bib archive for the bibliography, I need to compile the whole thing eventually with BibTex. However, this doesn't seem to work, and I don't understand why.

Some more clarifications: In order to compile the file I'm using TexMaker with MikTeX, and it insists that it needs the flag "-shell-escape" to compile. To do this, I'm using this precise command line to compile it into a PDF, and it creates the pdf, but without bibliography:

```
lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

I compile it twice as it is necessary to fully create the logs so that BibTex could (ideally) identify all the citations. However when I run the BibTex Command, it generates this error and DOESN'T generate any bibliography:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 23.4) The top-level auxiliary file: TFM.aux I couldn't open auxiliary file contenido/TFM-05_SeleccionAtrib.aux ---line 28 of file TFM.aux : \@input{contenido/TFM-05_SeleccionAtrib.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file contenido/TFM-11_Apendice_2.aux ---line 33 of file TFM.aux : \@input{contenido/TFM-11_Apendice_2.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no \citation commands---while reading file TFM.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file TFM.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file TFM.aux (There were 5 error messages)
```

And it generates the PDF file, but when I try to compile it with lualatex again with the same command as above, it still doesn't generate the PDF with bibliography. Is there something I'm missing? Please help...

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I'm writing this for any future readers. Also, I'm using TexStudio now, because it has a much nicer environment than texmaker (although this might be personal preference).

So, the template above requires three specific things that were causing problems:

1. The "minted" package
2. LuaLatex as compiler
3. Biber as compiler for the bibliography

The package minted requires the flag "--shell-escape" to be included as part of the compiling command, and the entire template works only with "LuaLateX" as the compiler, so, the compiling command looks something like this:

```
lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

However, the "minted" package also needs a command called "pygmentize" that is available in a PYTHON package called "Pygments" (so those two must be installed), so I also had to make two additions to the "Paths" environment variable of Windows so that it points at the files both of "python" and the package "pygments".

Finally, the bibliography must be included in a standard Bibtex.bib file, but since this template uses biblatex as a package, the compiler for the bibliography must be Biber:

```
biber %
```

Keeping that in mind, the entire thing has to be compiled like in any other document that uses bibtex, so the compilation order would be something like:

1. lualatex
2. biber
3. lualatex
4. lualatex

One last thing, with regard to the citing: always use the command "\cite" to make a citation, and if there are other references that you want to include but are not directly cited, you can use the command "\nocite{*}" just before printing the bibliography. So the bibliography page of the template above would be something like:

```
\cleardoublepage
\nocite{*}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
```